# Django 2 Create Model Programmatically

Tags: django

I'm looking to auto-register app and create a Django model within the app programmatically, upon using `manage.py startapp newapp --template=quicktemplate`. My thought process is as below, but I only got up to auto-register app. But then, the whole process feels too hacky, and I very much welcome any Django-approved way. I also looked up for `migrations.CreateModel` API, but it's too complex for my novice understanding.

In my project-wide settings.py, I scan for folders which are not non-app folders i.e. project-level folder called `quick`. Here, I auto-register any new folders as app into `INSTALLED_APPS`. Probably I will need to restart Django server to reload the setting file, but I live with that for now.

```
# quick/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
                    ... # django contribs
                 ]

NON_APP_FOLDERS = ['quick', 'quicktemplate', 'media']
APP_LIST = [ app for app in next(os.walk('.'))[1] if
             app not in NON_APP_FOLDERS ]
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + APP_LIST
```

In my quicktemplate, I have created initial model, and also update apps.py for the model initialization.

```
# quicktemplate/models.py
# declare model that will be initialized once upon app creation

from django.db import models

class AppProfile (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

...

```
# quicktemplate/__init__.py
# to allow AppConfig ready() to be called

default_app_config = '{{ app_name }}'.apps.'{{ camel_case_app_name }}'
```

...

```
#quicktemplate/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
    name = {{ app_name }}

    def ready(self):
        # NOT SURE HOW TO INITIALIZE 'AppProfile' MODEL IN 'models.py'
```

To summary, I need to know what statements go into `ready(self)` function, to create model programmatically. However, any improved and cleaner full solution is very much welcome.

Comment: looking to develop company in-house rapid application development tool. Using manage.py startapp, the new app is "90% there" except for developing forms and app-specific models. There are common models across all new apps, so this is the one I want to be auto-generated.